# Enable a button android from a different Activity

Tags: android, button, android-activity

In my code I have a disabled button in the `activity 'A'`
Can I enable that button on the `activity 'A'` from an `activity 'B'`?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what's the case and what you're trying to do?

Comment: Question is not clear.. please elaborate more so that you get correct solution.

Comment: yes, sorry. I explain my problem better. I have a main screen 'A' which has a button and from 'A' call 'B' which is a configuration screen. And I want that when 'B' is finished, the button is enabled.
This is done via intent? How?

Comment: I suggest having a look at startActivityForResult() in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) and perhaps this can provide some inspiration in posting a more specific question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally, you cannot.

If you are invoking activity A from activity B, then you can pass information on whether to enable the button via the intent.

If A invoked B and you need to do something back in A based on user's actions in B, then you can invoke B with `startActivityForResult` and send the result back from B to A; then in `onActivityResult` of your activity A you can enable/disable the button based on what B has passed back.

Comment: I have a main screen 'A' which has a button and from 'A' call 'B' which is a configuration screen. And I want that when 'B' is finished, the button is enabled. This is done via intent? How?

Comment: What you are describing is the scenario I described in my last paragraph.  This is a straight-forward `startActivityForResult`/`onActivityResult` combination.  Have a look at http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/commontasks.html#opennewscreen and specifically sub-section titled "Returning a Result from a Screen"

Answer (score -2):

Use one `Global class` and declare `static boolean flag` variable

and `set flag value` as you want and  set Button's property `btn.setEnabled(Global.flag);`

Comment: First, using global static variables is not generally a good idea.  It's usually a sign of a bad design.  Second, this will not achieve the desired results, because setting a flag will not trigger any code to enable/disable a button.  If you just set a flag, then where/at what point/in what thread or activity will the button be enabled or disabled?

Comment: As Aleks G said above, global variables are not a good design (for most cases anyway) If you have a mechanism to pass information between activities the startActivityForResult and intents, why rely on a global variable? Also you don't propose a way to trigger the action that would change the variable's value and what would be checking the variable to propagate that to the Button.