# How to disable a button from another activity?

Tags: java, android

So, I have a menu activity and there a user can choose a game to play. When he does that, in game he has an option to go back to menu (either on backPress or on my Exit button in game). I need, when that happens, to disable that game button, so the user cannot play it again. How can I do that?

I tried to make an object from Menu class and then disable the button but get error. Also tried:

```
public void disableButton(){
        button.setEnabled(false);
    }
```

and then calling it:

```
obj.disableButton
```

But I get stactOverflow errors on line where I created my obj as soon my menu activity starts. How to do this?

EDIT:

In Menu class:

```
public void disableButton(){
        button.setEnabled(false);
    }
```

In Game class:

```
Menu objMenu = new Menu();
```

And then in exit onClickListener:

```
objMenu.disableButton();
```

EDIT2:

Here's how I call my game activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, Game.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, GAME);
```

Then in game activity:

```
Intent resp = new Intent();
                resp.putExtra("score", numberOfPoints);
                setResult(1, resp);
                finish();
```

And again in Menu class:

```
final private static int AS = 1;

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int respCode, Intent i) {
        if(respCode == 1) {
            switch(reqCode) {
                case AS: receivedA = i.getIntExtra("score", receivedA);
                button.setEnabled(false);
                            break;
}
```

So, this is what I do when game ends, and I disable that button succesfully.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10698485/enable-a-button-android-from-a-different-activity

Comment: create a method in class1 in which you will disable button and call this method from class2 if you dont want to use intents

Comment: Call your game with `startActivityForResult` and override `onActivityResult` in your menu activity.  Make sure to return a corresponding result from your game activity.

Comment: @newBee I tried that but get NullPoint exception error. I edited my original post, check out what I did.

Comment: On the click of the Start Button you start the game activity and also disable the button, so on back it will be disabled.

Comment: Not a bad idea at all. I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issues is not only in `button.setEnabled(false);`. As it is hard to say what is the problem without seeing code's details, I am suggesting another solution

1. start the game activity from menu activity using startActivityForResult
2. when the game is finished ,in the return intent put a specific data
3. In Menu activity, in onActivityResult check if the result intent has that specific data
4. basing on step 3 you can enable or disable the button

Comment: I do this for game finish. But I need to disable the button on back press or on my exit button, not when game ends.

Comment: wont it finish the game when you are pressing exit button?!

Comment: I've edited my post. So, you can see that I disable my button on game end. So how come it's not disabled when I press the back button? As you said, the game is also finished when I press the back button.

Comment: Well that's on of my games from main menu. I don't think the variable name is that important.

Comment: no you are starting activity using game .. but checking result using as.. use the same

Comment: do this startActivityForResult(i, AS);

Comment: I do exactly that, but I changed some of the variables and names here so you can understand the flow, my class names and variable names are different, my game class does not have GAME name, and my menu class does not have MENU menu. Start activityForResult works fine in my app, but still does not disable button on back press.